# what is better thing to do with rejected app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have created an application. It was rejected by apple as it has less content.

Now I have added functionality in it. what should I do with that app? should I submit it with same id or create new id for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same app, you should use the same app id. There should be no reason that you can't just re-submit it as the same app id as long as you've fixed whatever they rejected it for. Rejections happen all the time. If you've fixed what they wanted you to fix, they should accept it this time (barring any other issues).

Comment: Thanks! i was confused as it was my first rejection

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in submitting it with the same id.
Usually when Apple rejects your app they tell you the reason for it.
In my case, they also send me a link to the reference guide that I needed to fix my problem.